# iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

Tags: php, utf-8, utf-16, iconv, smpp

I am using Iconv function to convert string to requested character encoding. Look On Below Code

```
$sms_text =  'A:'f3*'F'; // Output received from SMPP
$result = iconv('UTF-16BE' ,'UTF-8//IGNORE' , $sms_text);
echo 'Ignore: ' .$result;

echo $sms_text = iconv('UTF-16BE' ,'UTF-8' , $sms_text);

$result1 = iconv('UTF-16BE' ,'UTF-8//TRANSLIT' , $sms_text); //line no (53)
echo 'Transilt: '.$result1;
```

And I received the below Output 
[image]

If I have a string of dari and pashto Language, then its showing only first word and dont return remaining string after blank space. Even //IGNORE gives the same output.

Should I replace these blank spaces with the help of with some other character so that I can get complete string?

Note: I am passing string received from SMPP(receiver).

```
SMS Sent to SMPP : افغانستان کابل
Outpur Received from SMPP : 'A:'f3*'F
String back converted by iconv : افغانستان
```

English string is working well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You are converting string to UTF-8 charset on this line:

```
echo $sms_text = iconv('UTF-16BE' ,'UTF-8' , $sms_text);
```

The error appears becouse you are trying to convert it second time.
To resolve this issue you should not update $sms_text variable on mentioned line.

Here is a code and output that works for me:

```
$sms_text ="فغانستان کابل";

echo "UTF-8 : $sms_text \n";

$sms_text = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE', $sms_text);

echo "UTF-16BE : $sms_text \n";

echo 'Ignore: ' . iconv('UTF-16BE' ,'UTF-8//IGNORE' , $sms_text) . "\n";
echo 'Simple: ' . iconv('UTF-16BE' ,'UTF-8' , $sms_text) . "\n";
echo 'Transilt: '. iconv('UTF-16BE' ,'UTF-8//TRANSLIT' , $sms_text) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
UTF-8 : فغانستان کابل 
UTF-16BE : A:'F3*'F
Ignore: فغانستان کابل
Simple: فغانستان کابل
Transilt: فغانستان کابل
```

As for blank spaces, could you please share the test string?

Comment: Dear @sergey, I am assigning $sms_text=A:'F3*'F to $sms_text because it is encoded string return by SMPP which is in UTF-16BE format.

Comment: SMS to SMPP : فغانستان کابل (UTF-8)
SMPP TO Me ($sms_text): A:'F3*'F (UTF-16BE)
Output should be : A:'F3*'F to فغانستان کابل (UTF-16BE to UTF-8)

Comment: Looks like you are recieving $sms_text and assigning it to $result. But you should not assign anything to $sms_text in your code fragment.

Comment: Please just try to remove "$sms_text = " from line 51 (third line of code in your sample) or replace with "$result2 = "

Comment: Could you please also show how are you sending the message?

Comment: No, I am just receiving by using SMPP Receiver. Messages are sent from somewhere else. I am just reading sms from that mobile device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56324/discussion-between-sergey-ivashchenko-and-sushil-kandola).